# Update cached file on form submit

Tags: php, mysql, caching

Hi I'm using [this script](https://github.com/joaoverissimo/SimpleCachePhp) to cache a query. (#SimpleCachePHP) And it basically works fine but for one thing. It always uses the cached results when I change and resubmit the search form. Is there a way to tweek the script so it will create a new file or update the cached file every time I submit the form?

Thx for your help!
Seb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is what I did. In case anybody wants to know.

I added another if clause to this:

```
public static function verificaCacheFile($filename, $time = 86400) {
    if (file_exists($filename) && (time() - $time < filemtime($filename))) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

now it checks for a form submit before looking for cached files:

```
public static function verificaCacheFile($filename, $time = 36000) {
    if (isset ($_POST['submit'])) {
        return false;
        }
    elseif (file_exists($filename) && (time() - $time < filemtime($filename))) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```